# Using a variable from one function in another function (parameter 'dice' unfilled)

Tags: python, random

Hi im trying to create a game where the computer generates 5 random numbers between 1 and 6. but my issue is i have created a list which will gain '1' in its respective section depending on what number comes up. e.g. if the computer generates 31534 the list needs to show [1,0,2,1,1,0] (because there was two 3's it fills 2 in the 3 slot) it only displays the 5 random numbers and nothing else

```
from random import randint

def rollDice():

    dice = [str(randint(1, 6)) for _ in range(5)]
    print(dice)
    return dice

#-----------------------------------------------------------------

def countVals(dice):

    totals = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    for x in dice:
        if x == 1:
            totals = totals[1] + 1
        elif x == 2:
            totals = totals[2] + 1
        elif x == 3:
            totals = totals[3] + 1
        elif x == 4:
            totals = totals[4] + 1
        elif x == 5:
            totals = totals[5] + 1

            print(totals)
            return totals

#------------------------------------------------------------------

rollDice()
countVals()
```

Comment: countVals(rollDice()) and remove str from rollDice(), why do you need to convert to string.

Comment: Please see http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ for code style guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that the result returned by your rollDice function is a list of strings. The if - else statement in countVals then falls through cause for example `'5' == 5 -> False`. You could modify rollDice to return a list of int's instead (don't convert your ints to strings):

```
def rollDice():

    dice = [randint(1, 6) for _ in range(5)]
    print(dice)
    return dice
```

If you absolutely want rollDice to return a list of strings you could convert the strings to ints using the `int` method in your countVals method. Example: `int('5') -> 5`, or just compare strings and not ints. `x == '5'`

Also make sure that you are saving your totals back to the right index in you totals list (in rollDice). You could do this a little more succinctly as follows: `totals[1] += 1`, for example:

```
def countVals(dice):

    totals = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] #alternatively could be 'totals = [0]*6' :)
    for value in dice:
        totals[value - 1] += 1

    print(totals)
    return totals
```

(assuming rollDice has been modified to return a list of integers)

You should be able to call the methods as follows `totals = countVals(rollDice())` to get your list of totals.

Comment: alright i will change that but i am getting an error parameter 'dice' unfilled

Comment: How are you calling this `countVals(rollDice())` ?

Comment: Also make sure totals starts with six elements (modified code above). The numbers could be 1,2,3,4,5 or 6.

Comment: alright so that seems to be almost doing it but the output is this: [4, 5, 2, 4, 5]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0]

Comment: This is the output I get by copy and pasting the above into a .py file and running it [3, 6, 1, 6, 4] -> [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2]. You might have a typo or something..

Answer (score 1):

I believe your error lies when you increment the count of each number,

```
totals = totals[1] + 1
```

should be,

```
totals[1] = totals[1] + 1
```

Also depending on your application you may be able to simplify your code

```
def countVals(dice):

    totals = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    for x in dice:
        totals[x - 1] += 1
    print (totals)
    return totals
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
dice = rollDice()
countVals(dice)
```

Also you want to fix the indentation of the `print` and `return` statements in `countVals()`.  Currently, they only trigger if `x==5`.  And as Salvador Dali mentions, either remove `str` from `rollDice()` or change the comparisons in `countVals()` to `x == '1'`, etc.

---

Edit:

Here is how you may want to write your script:

```
def rollDice():
    dice = [randint(1, 6) for _ in range(5)]
    print(dice)
    return dice

def countVals(dice):
    totals = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    for x in dice:
        # x can be, 1-5.  Index of totals can be 0-4.
        totals[x-1] += 1

        print(totals)
        return totals

dice = rollDice()
countVals(dice)
```

Comment: where am i ment to put 'dice = rollDice90'?